# A code is running perfectly fine in C++ but giving TLE in python on Leetcode

Tags: c++, python-3.x

I am solving a question on leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-size-subarray-sum/solution/
This problem is working perfectly fine with a logic in C++ but not giving TLE in same logic in Python. Can anyone please help me out.

**Code in C++**

```
int minSubArrayLen(int s, vector<int>& nums)
{
    int n = nums.size();
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    int ans = INT_MAX;
    vector<int> sums(n);
    sums[0] = nums[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        sums[i] = sums[i - 1] + nums[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
            int sum = sums[j] - sums[i] + nums[i];
            if (sum >= s) {
                ans = min(ans, (j - i + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return (ans != INT_MAX) ? ans : 0;
}
```

**Code in Python**

```
    def minSubArrayLen(self, s: int, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        n=len(nums)
        if n==0:
            return 0
        ans=math.inf
        sums=[0]*n
        sums[0]=nums[0]
        for i in range(1,n):
            sums[i]=sums[i-1]+nums[i]
            
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                summ=sums[j]-sums[i]+nums[i]
                if summ>=s:
                    ans=min(ans, (j-i+1))
                    break
        return ans if ans!=math.inf else 0
```

Similar kind of problem I'm facing in some other codes also. Can anyone please suggest how can I optimize my python code.

Comment: In python code, you're `jth` for loop range should be `range(i, n)` not `range(n)`

Comment: @AbhinavaBN I also noticed that mistake and have corrected it also. But still facing the same issue.